# Custom Formatter for .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I would like to use a custom formatter for .NET remoting. In order to accomplish this, my understanding is that I have to implement something akin to the BinaryClientFormatterSink class (used for BinaryFormatter), but for my custom formatter. For example, if my formatter was FastBinaryFormatter, I would likely implement FastBinaryClientFormatterSink. I would then configure remoting to use my FastBinaryClientFormatterSink in the configuration file by providing the tag: . I have been searching for an example of how this is done to no avail. Ultimately I would like to use this over a TCP channel. Where could I find a sample implementation of this?

Comment: Are you aware that Remoting is now deprecated in favor of WCF?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Our application currently uses remoting for some of its existing infrastructure and I did not want to upgrade that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300447.aspx) you can find a sample for custom formatters for .net remoting. In this example you can see how the messages are processed both on client and server side, and which parameters you have to handle to make it work properly.